# UIAlertController not showing on a modal UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, presentviewcontroller

In a viewcontroller(A) another viewcontroller(B) will appear as a modal VC.

Setting the following properties present VC(B) and present it to topViewController in key window is not working.

```
B.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
B.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[B setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];



- (void)presentViewControllerInKeyWindow:(UIViewController*)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{

    UIViewController *topViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    if(topViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {

        topViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        while(topViewController.presentedViewController) {
            topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController;
        }

    }

    [topViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:animated completion:completion];
}
```

No alertcontroller is showing instead throwing error. Error says a VC is already presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check do you have any property named inputView or inputAccessoryView. If yes then change those names and try.